# How to load font into react project

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a problem loading the correctly Avenir font family.

I put the Link into the head of my application, as a result:

- **I cannot bold text, it's simply not working, but font Family is applied correctly**

Here is the way of loading Font, in the main HTML file under head tag:

Problem may be in te link:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Avenir Web:300,400,600,700,800,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 


  </head>
```

Any Idea what is the problem?

Comment: How are you trying to make your text bold? I mean, at css level, what property are you using? There are many ways to "load fonts into a React project". Yours is the easiest way.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano I put it on paragraph font-weight: 800; or font-wight: bold; 
it's not working

Comment: I've just checked and that font is not available anymore (see [here](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Avenir Web:300,400,600,700,800,900)). You can search a substitute using [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/)

Comment: If you really need that specific font, you can search for the files elsewhere and then use something like [Font Squirrel Generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to create all needed assets for self hosting.

Answer (score 1):

So I do not use react often without a framework

My guess as to why this isn't working is that for react-dom to use the root node() to be the render parent. Are you doing something like this `ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));` ?

regardless of the, I've seen people use a package called [react-helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet#react-helmet) to fix problems with the document head.

Let us know if this fixes your problem.

Comment: Hey Leviathan thanks for the answer. Unfortunately didn't help. 
I think that link is a problem, I am trying to find some example of using this Avenir font